# Pegar valor que iria para o ID e colocar em outro local e salvar no banco de dados

Tags: php, javascript, json

Desejo MONITORAR o movimento do usuário a partir do APP Android, que estará configurado com o link do meu painel.

Tenho o seguinte código:

```js
---------------------------------------------------------------------

    var geocoder;
var map;
var marker;

//PARTE PRINCIPAL
  function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-18.8800397, -47.05878999999999);
    var options = {
        zoom: 5,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapa"), options);

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        draggable: true,
    });

    marker.setPosition(latlng);
}





//PARTE 000001
if(navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){ // callback de sucesso
        // ajusta a posição do marker para a localização do usuário
        marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude));
    }, 
    
    function(error){ // callback de erro
       alert('Para um melhor desempenho nas entregas, ative a sua localização!');
       console.log('Erro ao obter localização.', error);
    });
} else {
    console.log('Navegador não suporta Geolocalização!');
}
//**************************
//**************************




//PARTE 00002
window.onload = function() {
  var startPos;
  var geoOptions = {
  timeout: 10 * 1000,
  maximumAge: 5 * 60 * 1000
  }

  var geoSuccess = function(position) {
    startPos = position;
    document.getElementById('startLat').innerHTML = startPos.coords.latitude;
    document.getElementById('startLon').innerHTML = startPos.coords.longitude;
  };
  
 
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoSuccess, geoError, geoOptions);
};





//PARTE 00003
//ATUALIZAR NO BANCO DE DADOS           
function Atualiza_Posicao(){

$.ajax({
    data: {"lat": + POSICAO-LAT-AQUI, "lng": + POSICAO-LNG-AQUI},
        type:'POST',        
        dataType: 'json',
        url:"atualizar-posicao.php"});
        //******************
    

}




//atualiza o mapa a cada segundo predefinido 
function foo() {
    //Colocar as funções aqui
    Atualiza_Posicao();
    
}
setInterval(foo, 4000);  

//****************************************************
  
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Na "//PARTE 00002" do código tem isso:

```js
document.getElementById('startLat').innerHTML = startPos.coords.latitude;
    document.getElementById('startLon').innerHTML = startPos.coords.longitude;
```

Ao invés de mostrar o resultado disso aí na DIV, eu quero salvar no banco de dados a LATITUDE e a LONGITUDE, mas não tô conseguindo.

No caso, o resultado seria jogado para a "//PARTE 00003", mais precisamente em "POSICAO-LAT-AQUI" e "POSICAO-LNG-AQUI"

```js
    //ATUALIZAR NO BANCO DE DADOS           
    function Atualiza_Posicao(){

    $.ajax({
        data: {"lat": + POSICAO-LAT-AQUI, "lng": + POSICAO-LNG-AQUI},
            type:'POST',        
            dataType: 'json',
            url:"atualizar-posicao.php"});
            //******************
        

    }
```

Comment: Na pergunta apenas coloque conteúdo e contextualização técnica. Caso precise fazer contextualizações sociais use o campo de comentários.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se entendi corretamente, você precisa **enviar os dados que estão nos campos mencionados na requisição**:

`data: { lat: POSICAO-LAT-AQUI, lng: POSICAO-LNG-AQUI }`

É possível resgatar os valores que deseja após ter inserido os mesmos em algum ponto anterior do seu fluxo como [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage), variável onde alguns pontos do código possuam acesso em comum, algum campo escondido na página etc. **Apenas como exemplo**, podemos fazer isso na sua função `geoSuccess` (que se entendi corretamente, é o ponto onde temos os dados desejados) utilizando `sessionStorage`:

```
  var geoSuccess = function(position) {
    startPos = position;
    sessionStorage.setItem('startLat', startPos.coords.latitude);
    sessionStorage.setItem('startLon', startPos.coords.longitude);
  };
```

E resgatamos antes de fazer o envio:

`var startLat = sessionStorage.getItem('startLat');`

`var startLon = sessionStorage.getItem('startLon');`

Ao final do fluxo, teríamos o objeto abaixo:

`data: { lat: startLat, lng: startLon }`

Você também pode resgatar os dados dos elementos que populou anteriormente e usá-los durante o envio:

`var startLat = document.getElementById("startLat").textContent`

`vat startLon = document.getElementById("startLon").textContent`

Lembre-se de que `sessionStorage` (caso use) vai manter os dados na sessão atual, então caso precise dados atualizados da mesma sessão, **sobrescreva os valores anteriores para não ter dados antigos sendo enviados ou limpe-os em algum ponto**.

Espero ter ajudado de alguma forma.

Comment: Ruan, ele quer salvar num banco de dados, tem até um ajax e tag php na pergunta, não no armazenamento local

Comment: @RicardoPontual sim, o que respondi foi como *resgatar os valores que existem em um ponto do código em outro ponto* para envio posterior, apenas o exemplo que dei foi usando `sessionStorage` como um dos caminhos para continuar tendo acesso aos dados que precisam ser enviados depois. Ao final da resposta coloquei como ficaria o resgate posterior do próprio sessionStorage e envio na requisição ajax. Edito minha resposta caso não tenha ficado claro, sem problemas.

Comment: Muito obrigado, @RuanMontelo. Era isso mesmo!